# Method returning string but is assigned as string[]

Tags: powershell

I have this code:

```
[string]$emailBody = getEmailBody $firstName $emailTemplateFileContent

function getEmailBody($firstName, $emailTemplateFileContent)
{
    $sb = New-Object Text.StringBuilder
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt $emailTemplateFileContent.Length; $i++)
    {
        $sb.AppendLine($emailTemplateFileContent[$i])
    }
    $emailTemplateText = $sb.ToString()
    $emailTemplateTextCustomised = $emailTemplateText.Replace("#name", $firstName)

    return $emailTemplateTextCustomised
}
```

When I type `$emailTemplateTextCustomised.getType()` I can see that it is a `string`.

However when I type `$emailBody.getType()` I can see that it is an Array.

I can also see that the array has 8 strings, each string containing the output from `getEmailBody()`.

UPDATE:
Powershell seems really buggy, it is no longer a `String[]` but just a `String` with 8 repetitions of the output from `getEmailBody()`.

Why is it doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell isn't buggy, well at least not in this case. :-)  You have to understand that in PowerShell the "output" of a function is anything that is not captured to a variable.  The line that does the `StringBuilder.AppendLine()` returns the StringBuilder and that is added to the output of your function.  Try this:

```
function getEmailBody($firstName, $emailTemplateFileContent)
{
    $sb = New-Object Text.StringBuilder
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt $emailTemplateFileContent.Length; $i++)
    {
        $sb.AppendLine($emailTemplateFileContent[$i]) > $null
    }
    $emailTemplateText = $sb.ToString()
    $emailTemplateText.Replace("#name", $firstName)
```

}

If you are on V3 (maybe V2) you can use the -replace operator as well:

```
function getEmailBody($firstName, $emailTemplateFileContent)
{
    $sb = New-Object Text.StringBuilder
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt $emailTemplateFileContent.Length; $i++)
    {
        $sb.AppendLine($emailTemplateFileContent[$i]) > $null
    }
    $emailTemplateText = $sb.ToString() -replace '#name',$firstName
    $emailTemplateText 
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!
I'm still a bit confused, what do you mean the StringBuilder.AppendLine() returns a StringBuilder, where does it return it to?
In my code, the only variable I am returning is the $emailTemplateTextCustomised which in debug I can see is a normal string without 8 repitions of itself.

Comment: The "return value" of that method is a StringBuilder instance. You don't assign that to a variable (or redirect to null) so that object is added to your function's output.

Comment: Casting to `void` also works to avoid outputting values to the pipeline: `[void]$sb.AppendLine($emailTemplateFileContent[$i])`

Comment: Yes, as does piping to `Out-Null`.

Comment: By the way, `StringBuilder` has its own [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.replace.aspx) method.